# Construct std::function with a constructor based on template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

Is it possible to construct a `std::function` with the constructor of a type defined by a template argument?

For example:

```
template <typename T>
bool registerType()
{
    const std::function<T()> func = &T::T; //I know this doesn't work
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think so, because constructors don't have names, you can't take a pointer/reference to them, and in general they don't behave quite like functions.

You could use a lambda to initialize a `std::function` with the same signature:

```
const std::function<T()> func = [](void) { return T(); } // or something like that
```

Calling it produces the same result as using the expression `T()` to construct a temporary of type `T`, but possibly with different side-effects. In the case of a true function call there's an extra temporary in the return statement, which nominally is copied/moved to the return value. The implementation may or may not elide the extra temporary.