# How to convert a constructor to a std::function

Tags: c++

Is there any way to assign a constructor to a function like 'f':

```cpp
struct C
{
    C(int){};
};

auto f = C::C(int); // not work
auto g = [](int){ return C(int()); }; // works
```

Neither C, C::C, &C, &C::C, C::&C, C::C(int), &C::C(int) ... works

**Solution proposed by Friday Pie:**

```cpp
template <class T>
struct ConstructHelper
{
    template <class... Args>
    static T&& construct(Args&&... args)
    {
        return std::move(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
};

auto f = ConstructHelper<C>::construct<int>; // works
auto c = apply(f, 0); // works
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Construct std::function with a constructor based on template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386725/construct-stdfunction-with-a-constructor-based-on-template) and/or [Assign a constructor to an std::function variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49661673/364696).

Comment: What you are trying to do does not make sense.

Comment: @Eugene similar to `apply(func, args...)`, we should have `apply(cls, args...)` in c++

Comment: Are you asking for `allocator_traits<C, Args...>::construct`? But then: who provides the memory location where `C` is constructed in? That's the reason it makes no sense.

Comment: A constructor does not have a type nor an address, and cannot be explicitly called in a function-call-expression. It does not return anything, not even `void`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you tried to write follows other rules than than the lambda that you wrote.

In the first one, you are trying to get a pointer to a member function: `&C::C` This would be similar to `&C::print` (assuming argument int) The first argument of this function would be a pointer to C, the second would the the int.

However, we are trying to do this for the constructor. So we don't have a valid C to work on. The result is that this simply doesn't compile.

Note that if you do want to execute a constructor on existing memory, you need placement new.

Your second code is a lambda. In short: a class with `operator()` implemented. And in this operator, you write code as in any other function and return a newly constructed instance by value. (Although, this looks a lot like a vexing parse) Tis is similar to executing the print function that was mentioned before.

So both would have different semantics and your compiler is right in failing to compile this code.

Answer (score 1):

In theory your hypothetical function `apply` would look quite simple as a template

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
struct C
{
    C(int){};
};

template <class F, class... Args>
auto apply ( F&& f, Args&&... args) -> typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type
{
    return f(args...);
}

float foo (int a, float b) {  return a*b; }

int main()
{
    auto b = apply(&foo, 3, 5.f);
    //auto b = apply(&C::C, 3);  //error: taking address of constructor 'C::C'

    return 0;
}
```

But it is impossible to take address of constructor, as per the ISO standard. In most cases this special function is a non-entity in resulting code.

Neither explicit call to constructor is allowed. Your lambda function  does thing differently. It constructs an object of class `C` as to per defined effect of that expression.

You could use a bogus argument and SFINAE

```
 template <class F, class... Args>
    auto apply ( F&& f, Args&&... args) 
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable<F, Args...>::value,
           typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
{
    return f(args...);
}

template <class T, class... Args>
auto apply ( T&&, Args&&... args)
    -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_invocable<T, Args...>::value,T&&>
{
    return std::move(T(args...));
}
```

but it's preferable to avoid that and rethink whatever meta-programming pattern you have in mind, i.e. avoid attempt to call same template name for different kinds of arguments, or make amends with lambda use. E.g. you may avoid to call `apply()` by using SFINAE.

Comment: So there is no way to make a `apply` call to construct a non-default-constructable and non-copy-constructable class in C++11?

Comment: i.e. C(1, 2, 3) vs apply(some-constructor-func, 1, 2, 3) where C is non-default-constructable and non-copy-constructable

Comment: @MidoriYakumo should be able to create movable one. And usually non-default, non-copyable classes are very special. Like singletons or unique authority holders (e.g. something like `unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`)

Comment: @MidoriYakumo your C is copyable. It's not movable though. To not be copyable it have to have: `C(const C&) = delete;` or `C(C&& o)` explicitly declared. It should be either movable or copyable or assignments above won't work.